# Bevel Modifier + smooth shading produces black artefacts at high angle

Tags: modifiers

I have recognized a strange reflection behavior which I can't fix properly

At high camera angle the bevel modifier (and also beveling corners via the modeling tools) produces artefacts in combination with a reflective material and the smooth shading. (In the picture at the top corner and on the left corner)

It does not depends on the material (with or without Layer Weight, changing the fresnel values) or the use of the objects Auto Smooth settings. The world background is completely white and there is no other object which would be reflected.

At the second picture you can see both variants:
Top row = Cube with Bevel Modifier (settings on the right), activated smooth shading and Auto Smooth

Bottom row = Cube with modeled beveling (Ctrl+B), same settings as above.

I barely solved it by increasing the segments. (Its always there but very small)

Does anyone have a tip to fix it in a better way?

Thank you in advance & regards!

**[image: strong text]**

[image]

Comment: did you enable Auto Smooth under Mesh Data?

Comment: @Noidea It doesn't matter if I switch Auto Smooth on or off. By turning the smooth Angle down it disappears but then it looks like flat shading again.

Comment: Well, I can only tell what helped me in similar situation. I added "Edge Split" modifier. But your problem does look a bit different.

Comment: What are the settings of the Bevel modifier and what is the topology of the base cube.. I couldn't achieve that with default cube and clamp checked for modifier.

Comment: @MrZak I added a second picture, with the settings and both variants, modifier and  modeled bevel.

Comment: Now it's more clear how to get that. That's because of smooth shading which makes the center big face kind of convex. If you add loopcuts and slide them to the corner (almost, just not ruining the bevel) that will mitigate the problem because making the big central face flat (loopcuts will do that).